# Julia While Loop not Working as Expected

Tags: while-loop, julia

I'm having trouble understanding a problem I have with my Julia while loops. Here's a simple example:

```
i = 1
while i <10
    bb = 2
    i = i + 1
end

bb

bb not defined
while loading In[36], in expression starting on line 1
```

My question is how is bb not defined here? Is this a problem of scope? I don't think it is, because i is incremented to 10 at the end.

Comment: Try initializing `bb = 2` outside of the while block. Modifying it from within the while block should then work and it will be accessible once the while loop completes.

Comment: This doesn't work either:    b = 10 , while i < 10
       b += i,
       i += 1
       end  ; b  still = 10 at the end. it is unchanged

Comment: Adding global does work. I don't see in the documentation that while/for loops are local in scope? Where can I find more information about this? Thank you

Comment: Initializing sees to work pretty well, see http://goo.gl/1S6Thw

Comment: @JeremyMcNees Sorry I was wrong. For function scope it seems necessary to put global but for for/while it seems not necessary according to the [manual](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/)

Comment: Yeah this seems strange. Maybe it's an issue with <0.4 Julia? I'm using 0.3.9. Adding global does work, but I'm not sure why it's necessary. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @JeremyMcNees your example is invalid syntax. The following works as expected on 0.3.6, 0.3.10, and 0.4-dev. `b = 10; i=1; while i < 10 b += i; i += 1 end`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the [*Scope of Variables*](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/) section of the Julia manual, `while` loops introduce unique scope blocks. So, in the given example, `bb` is [**local**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) to the `while` loop. To make `bb` available outside the loop, declare it first:

```
julia> i = 1; bb = 10
10

julia> while i <10
           bb = 2
           i = i + 1
       end

julia> bb
2
```